# Auto Submitting a form periodically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would to like to submit a form recursively using jquery at a particular period of time is there a way to do so?

Comment: Use `setInterval` and trigger `form.submit`

Comment: What does this has to do with jQuery-ui..?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with setInterval, for example:

```
<script>
window.setInterval(sendForm, 3000);  // 3000 millisecons, or 3 sec

function sendForm() {
    //get the action-url of the form
    var actionurl = document.getElementById("theForm").action;

    //do your request an handle the results
    $.ajax({
            url: actionurl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $("#theform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                // You don't really want a window alert here, since
                // it will block the execution. Only used for demo
                // here you'd run the code after your form submits
                // succesfully
                window.alert("Submitted form");
            }
    });

}

</script>
<form id="theForm" method="POST" action="myReceiver.php">
  <input type="text" value="demo value">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [setTimeout](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/) javascript function.